# Is search speed achieved with fast data access or fast index access?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

From [MySQL doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html):

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
    (create_definition,...)
    {DATA|INDEX} DIRECTORY [=] 'absolute path to directory'
```

My table is for search only and takes 8G of disk space (4G data + 4G index) with 80M rows
I can't use `ENGINE = Memory` to store the whole table into memory but I can store either the data or the index in a RAM drive through the `DIRECTORY` table options

From a theorical knoledge, is it better to store the data or the index in RAM?

Comment: It depends on what you want, and what a typical query looks like for your domain. The best thing to do is to try both scenarios, hitting the database with 'typical' queries, and seeing how they compare in speed.

Comment: I would guess that fast indexing would be preferable if a typical query returns either a small number of rows, or is stored with a small number of bytes per row; and I guess the opposite would create a larger initial cost for all queries, but a performance benefit for larger queries. But, this is just a guess, and you'll know more than me once you've tried it.

Comment: What I want is speed. Any theorical answer is welcome if his has never been experimenced before

Comment: @guigoz Have you considered trying each one and doing your own performance tests?

Comment: Let's see `CREATE TABLE` and the `SELECT` query that you are trying to optimize.  We can probably find ways to speed up the query _without_ doing what you are asking in this Question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL's default storage engine is InnoDB. As you run queries against an InnoDB table, the portion of that table or indexes that it reads are copied into the [InnoDB Buffer Pool](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html) in memory. This is done automatically. So if you query the same table later, chances are it's already in memory.

If you run queries against other tables, it load those into memory too. If the buffer pool is full, it will need to evict some of the data that belongs to your first table. This is not a problem, since it was only a copy of what's on disk.

There's no way to specifically "lock" a table on an index in memory. InnoDB will load either data or index if it needs to. InnoDB is smart enough not to evict data you used a thousand times, just for one other table requested one time.

Over time, this tends to balance out, using memory for your most-frequently queried subset of each table and index.

So if you have system memory available, allocate more of it to your InnoDB Buffer Pool. The more memory the Buffer Pool has, the more able it is to store all the frequently-queried tables and indexes.

Up to the size of your data + indexes, of course.  The content copied from the data + indexes is stored only once in memory. So if you have only 8G of data + indexes, there's no need to give the buffer pool more and more memory.

Don't allocate more system memory to the buffer pool than your server can afford. Overallocating memory leads to swapping memory for disk, and that will be bad for performance.

Don't bother with the `{DATA|INDEX} DIRECTORY` options. Those are for when you need to locate a table on another disk volume, because you're running out of space. It's not likely to help performance. Allocating more system memory to the buffer pool will accomplish that much more reliably.

Comment: That's the science I'm looking for! Actually there will not be frequently queries done, each query will be likely new so the cache might not help. This is why I'm looking for a way to pre-use memory (a king of fore cache)

Comment: It will work if your queries are different. The copy in the buffer pool is the source data, not the results of queries. Any query that needs the same portion of a table or index can re-use what's in the buffer pool.

Comment: But I can't say in advance that a query will need the same portion of a table or index. The buffers are doing their job indeed, I did observe it while testing but in real life it won't be the case. Ok I can tell the users to wait for the result, but if there's a way I can do better then I'd like to use it

Comment: You don't need to know what portion a query will need. InnoDB will automatically load data pages into the buffer pool if they aren't already in memory.

Comment: You should also consider that query design and index design are also important. It's common to write an inefficient SQL that is still slow even if all data is in memory. Likewise, a well-designed query can be fast even on a server without a lot of memory.

Comment: Every time I stop to answer a MySQL question, I find that @BillKarwin has beaten me there and did a better job than I could have :)

Answer (score 2):

> *but I can store either the data or the index in a RAM drive through the DIRECTORY table options...*

Short answer: let the database and OS do it.

Using a RAM disk might have made sense 10-20 years ago, but these days the software manages caching disk to RAM for you. The disk itself has its own RAM cache, especially if it's a [hybrid drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_drive). The OS will cache file system access in RAM. And then MySQL itself will do its own caching.

And if it's an SSD that's already extremely fast, so a RAM cache is unlikely to show much improvement.

So making your own RAM disk isn't likely to do anything that isn't already happening. What you *will* do is pull resources away from the OS and MySQL that they could have managed smarter themselves likely slowing everything on that machine down.

---

What you're describing a ***micro-optimization***. This is attempting to make individual operations faster. They tend to add complexity and degrade the system as a whole. And there are limits to how much optimizing you can do with micro-optimizations. For example, if you have to search 1,000,000 rows, and it takes 1ms per row, that's 1,000,000 ms. If you make it 0.9ms per row then it's 900,000 ms.

What you want to focus on is ***algorithmic optimization***, improvements to the algorithm. These tend to make the code simpler and less complex, though often the data structures need to be more thought out, because you're doing less work. Take those same 1,000,000 rows and add an index. Instead of looking at 1,000,000 rows you'll spend, say, 100 ms to look at the index.

The numbers are made up, but I hope you get the point. If "what you want is speed", algorithmic optimizations will take you where no micro-optimization will.

There's also the performance of the code using the database to consider, it is often the real bottleneck using unoptimized queries, poor patterns for fetching related data, and not taking advantage of caching.

Micro-optimizations, with their complexities and special configurations, tend to make algorithmic optimizations more difficult. So you might be slowing yourself down in the long run by worrying about micro-optimizations now. Furthermore, you're doing this at the very start when you only have fuzzy ideas about how this thing will be used or perform or where the bottlenecks will be.

Spend your time optimizing your data structures and indexes, not minute details of your database storage. Once you've done that, if it still isn't fast enough, then look at tweaking settings.

---

As a side note, there is one ***possible*** benefit to playing with `DIRECTORY`. You can put the data and index on separate physical drives. Then both can be accessed simultaneously with the full I/O throughput of each drive.

Though you've just made it twice as likely to have a disk failure, and complicated backups. You're probably better off with an SSD and/or RAID.

And consider whether a cloud database might actually out-perform any hardware you might be able to afford.

Comment: I already ran into query optimization, structure optimization, index optimization, I even had to `FORCE INDEX` because MySQL did not use the right one, so I'm getting interested in any other optimization not related to code

Comment: Why "not related to code"? You can make the fastest database in the world, but it doesn't matter if it's used inefficiently. And if you have these details of what's being stored and how it's being used, they would help to answer your question in more detail.

Comment: No, because I don't know what matters most when a query is issued: data access or index access?

Comment: @guigoz Again, I believe you're focusing on the wrong end of the performance problem. You're asking about your solution (attempting to increase i/o performance of raw data & index access), not about the performance problem this is supposed to solve. If you give us more information about the performance problem, we can better help you find a solution. Samples from the slow query log, for example.